# How to dynamically get the UID of the IOS simulator device and then install in that device

Tags: ios, xcode, bash, appium, ios-simulator

How to dynamically get the UID of the IOS simulator device and then install it in that device. I currently have this BASH script which does the job, however, when I run that code on a different machine, I need to manually change the ID every time which makes the automation difficult. How can I get the UID just by defining the device type such as IPHONE.8 get the ID and use that instead

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# define variables
DESTINATION="platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 8,OS=13.4.1"
IPHONE_VERSION_ONE="iPhone-7"
APPDIR="$HOME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/"
APP_NAME="In-House-iphonesimulator/test.app"
PHONE_ID_ONE="AB877AA-2178-4C29-BF4F-556456C"


xcrun simctl install $PHONE_ID_ONE $APP_LOCATION || { echo 'Unable to install App to Iphone7' ; exit 1; }
```

Also i put the below answer in the variable, however how to put quotes when store it in a variable?

```
PHONE_ID="instruments -s devices | grep -m 1 "iPhone 8" | awk -F'[][]' '{print $2}'"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`instruments -s devices | grep "iPhone 8" | awk -F'[][]' '{print $2}'`

Here what this command is doing:

1. Listing all of your iOS devices
2. Searching for `iPhone 8` over the results
3. Splitting the string by square brackets and printing the second token.

So you as a result should get UDID only: `XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX`

If you have more than one iPhone 8 simulator in your system, you can limit the output by adding `-m 1` key to the grep command:

```
instruments -s devices | grep -m 1 "iPhone 8" | awk -F'[][]' '{print $2}'
```

Just assign the result of this command to your `PHONE_ID_ONE` variable using `$()`:

```
PHONE_ID="$(instruments -s devices | grep -m 1 'iPhone 8' | awk -F'[][]' '{print $2}')"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you so much, this worked for me, this is what i was looking for

Comment: the only question i have is how to put quotes around it when i store it in a variable? - PHONE_ID=instruments -s devices | grep -m 1 "iPhone 8" | awk -F'[][]' '{print $2}'

Comment: @Poonam, here is how assignment could be done:
`PHONE_ID="$(instruments -s devices | grep -m 1 'iPhone 8' | awk -F'[][]' '{print $2}')"`

Answer (score 3):

I have used below command to get the device id of launched Simulator.

```
xcrun simctl list devices | grep "(Booted)" | grep -E -o -i "([0-9a-f]{8}-([0-9a-f]{4}-){3}[0-9a-f]{12})"
```

We can get the id of specified device by given device name if there are multiple devices are launched

```
xcrun simctl list devices | grep "(Booted)" | grep "iPhone 12" |grep -E -o -i "([0-9a-f]{8}-([0-9a-f]{4}-){3}[0-9a-f]{12})"
```

Answer (score 2):

With xctrace for example

```
   xctrace list  devices | grep -m 1 "iPhone 12" | awk '{print substr($0,length($0)-36,36)}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of simulators together with their ID :

```
instruments -s devices
```

Comment: Yes, i am aware of that command but i want to extract the id of the iphone 8 then use that in the command. I do not know how to do that